# Widget selection and mouse event handling in a Matlab figure having several widgets

Tags: matlab, event-handling, widget, matlab-figure, mousewheel

I am trying to handle events nicely in a `figure` that contains several widgets. On one hand, only `figure` has a `WindowScrollWheelFcn` (if I focus on the mouse wheel for now). On the  other hand, when I create a figure containing two lists, like

```
h_fig = figure();
strs = arrayfun(@num2str, [1:100], 'UniformOutput', false);
uicontrol(h_fig, 'Style', 'list', 'Units', 'normalized', 'Position', [0.6 0 1 1], 'String', strs);
uicontrol(h_fig, 'Style', 'list', 'Units', 'normalized', 'Position', [0 0 0.4 1], 'String', strs);
```

the mouse wheel event is captured and processed by the selected list only. Furthermore, selecting a list unselects the other list, as expected.

Now I am looking to insert my own widget in there, and I would like my custom widget to handle exactly as those lists. How to write a widget that would integrate with the widget selection mechanism that is apparent in the example above? That is, that could disable other widgets (custom and built-in like lists) as well as being disabled. I suppose once this is in place, writing a `WindowScrollWheelFcn` that operates on the selected widget only would be straightforward.

Comment: I don't understand what you're asking.

Comment: @excaza In the figure with two lists above, add an axis, and write a `WindowScrollWheelFcn` callback that, say, change the color of the axis background only when the axis is selected.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm fairly sure that scrolling of `list`-style `uicontrol`s happens outside of MATLAB's event handling framework, at the Java level.

However you can detect the currently-selected object from your callback using [`gco`](http://mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/gco.html). This will correctly return the `uicontrol` that is scrolling if one of those is selected, and would do the same thing for `axes`. You just need to be careful how you handle selection of child objects, such as if a `line` plotted on your `axes` was selected and you still want the scroll wheel event to affect those `axes`.